# Django form in a modal: redirect and handle errors dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a login form inside a modal window using Django. Basically, I am following [this](https://dmorgan.info/posts/django-views-bootstrap-modals/) tutorial. It works well but I would like to redirect the user to his/her personal page after the form is submitted and validated. Based on the previous guide I think I have to change the code in the highlighted part:

```
$(form).submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if ($(xhr).find('.has-error').length > 0) {
                    $(modal).html(xhr);
                    formAjaxSubmit(form, modal);
                } else {
                    $(modal).modal('hide');
                    ###########################
                    REDIRECT HERE TO ACTION URL
                    ###########################
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // handle response errors here
            }
        });
    });
```

However, I don't know if this is the correct solution nor if this is possible in this case.

Comment: I think you need to add your redirect code in the highlighted part. That looks correct and will work.

Comment: Yes.. But how can I retrieve the resulting url of the form action?

Comment: You are trying to redirect the user to his profile page right? It should be having an URL pattern right? Try using that.

Comment: Or you can return the redirect URL from your views and retrieve it here in your AJAX function.

Answer (score 0):

When you say personal page, that should really be an implicit thing i.e. site.com/dashboard which shows the user currently logged in dashboard. If you want to have redirects for something like a next link (i.e. user attempts to access page needs to log in) or similar, you could always pass the next link back in the response to the xhr request.